# Javascript timeout doesn't work after 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, session, zend-framework, refresh, settimeout

I'm trying to make a mechanism to refresh user's session on a website which is using Zend Framework 1. The target is to make the session longer than it is now (30 minutes for PHP session). I have a mechanism which can refresh the PHP session before the timeout. I'm triggering it by AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/index/keep",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (result)
   { ... }
});
```

This call is made by a function which first checks the last user's action on a page using PHP and session cookies and than compares it to actual time.

```
var startT=new Date;
var korekta=<?=time();?>-startT.getTime()/1000;
var refreshCount = 0;
var refreshTime = 3; // [min]
var warningTime = 17; // [min]
var logoutTime = 19; // [min]
var min2seconds = 60;
var functionRefresh = 30; // [s]
```

Above are some parameters for this function that are being set when the page is loaded. Below im presenting the code of function which check if time from last action is longer than these set in parameters (warningTime, logoutTime). After passing warningTime the websites showes warning in which user can continue (manually refresh session) or logout. After passing logoutTime user is forced to logout.

```
var t=c.substring(name.length, c.length);
var now=new Date;
var tt=(now.getTime()/1000)-t+korekta;

if(tt > min2seconds*warningTime)
{

        $('#logoutPopup').dialog(
        {
            modal: true,
            maxWidth: '70%',
            width:'60%',
            title: "Session expires",
            buttons:
            {
                "Continue": function()
                {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/index/keep",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result )
                        { refreshCount = 0;}
                    });
            },
            "Logout": function()
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                window.location.href="<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/index/logout";
            }
            }
        });
}

if(tt > min2seconds*logoutTime)
{
    window.location.href="<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/index/logout";
}
else if( tt > (refreshCount+1) * min2seconds*refreshTime )
{
    refreshCount++;
    $.ajax({
        url:        "<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/index/refresh",
        type:       "POST",
        dataType:   "json",
        success: function(result)
        {console.log("Refreshed " + refreshCount.toString() + " times.");}
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: "<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/index/blank",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result )
    { }
});
```

The function in which this code works is called every 30 seconds using:

```
setTimeout(checkLastActivity,functionRefresh*1000);
```

where *checkLastActivity* is the name of this function. The whole mechanism works perfectly when times are set below 20 minutes. After that javascripts stops to call this function and I don't know why. I used console.log function to print actual time on each *checkLastActivity* function call and it prints until ~20 minutes. Other javascript/jquery functions works on the page, just this one stops...

I've added additional AJAX call that calls *blank* action of *index* controller. This does nothing but was one of the solutions to similiar problem. Doesn't helps in this case.

To summarize: the goal is to make this function work when the *warningTime* is set to e.g. 35 minutes.

Comment: Is `setTimeout(checkLastActivity,functionRefresh*1000);` supposed to be `setInterval(checkLastActivity,functionRefresh*1000);`?

Comment: Does this occur while that browser tab is active, or when it is in background? I would suggest checking TTL more frequently

Comment: @csp713 It may be but I found discussion about it and setTimeout() should be used for applicatons like this.

Comment: @charlietfl Unfortunately both.